# How to hide RecyclerView items which should not be shown in the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an Android Chat application using Firebase as its backend.I have used RecyclerView in the layout which shows users who are using the chat application at the moment. In order to populate the RecyclerView I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter object.

What I want to do is, Show users who are near by in the RecyclerView. So I am getting their locations and calculate the distance to my current location.

I want to stop adding users who are far away from my location, to the RecyclerView. I have put setVisibility(View.GONE) though still recyclerView shows empty space.
How can I solve this problem

Code:

```
private void friendsLoad() {
    friendsAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserDetailsClass, FriendsViewHolder>(
            UserDetailsClass.class,
            R.layout.friend_online,
            FriendsViewHolder.class,
            tempUserRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final FriendsViewHolder viewHolder, UserDetailsClass model, int position) {

            if (model.getUserID().equals(UserDetails.getString("UniqueID", "ID"))) {
                sender = model.getName();
                viewHolder.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.mView.setY(0);
                viewHolder.mView.setWillNotDraw(false);
            }
            if (!model.getUserID().equals(UserDetails.getString("UniqueID", "ID"))) {

                // Calculate Distance
                distanceCalculator = new DistanceCalculator(latitude, longitude);
                distanceCalculator.calculate(model.getLatitude(), model.getLongitude());

                double distance = distanceCalculator.getDistanceInMeters();

                if (distance >= 8000) {
                    viewHolder.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (distance >= 4000 && distance < 8000) {
                    Log.i("Distance", "More than 4 Km");
                    viewHolder.friendName.setText(model.getName());
                    viewHolder.stateName.setText("");
                    viewHolder.distance.setText("Not Near By");
                    viewHolder.distance.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                if (2000 <= distance && distance < 4000) {
                    Log.i("Distance", "More less 4 Km and more than 2Km");
                    viewHolder.friendName.setText(model.getName());
                    viewHolder.stateName.setText(model.getStateName());
                    viewHolder.distance.setText("Approachable");
                    viewHolder.distance.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.skyBlue));

                }
                if (distance < 2000) {
                    Log.i("Distance", "less than 1 Km");
                    viewHolder.friendName.setText(model.getName());
                    viewHolder.stateName.setText(model.getStateName()); // Setting up the City name
                    viewHolder.distance.setText("Near By");
                    viewHolder.distance.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.commandoGreen));
                }

                //End of calculating distance

                if (model.getOnline_offline_status() == 1) {
                    viewHolder.online.setText("Online");
                    viewHolder.online.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkGreen));
                }
                if (model.getOnline_offline_status() == 0) {
                    viewHolder.online.setText("");
                }

            }


            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Log.i("TAG", "Clicked");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ChatHomeActivity.this, NewMessageList.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Sender", sender);
                    intent.putExtra("Receiver", viewHolder.friendName.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to not hide the views in the `ViewHolder`, but let the `adapter` of the recyclerview filter out those you don't want in the list.

Comment: Why don't you just filter the Adapter list?

Comment: Setting the views inside the recycler to GONE is the wrong approach. RecyclerViews reuse their views, and so when the view is recycled, its visibility would need to be adjusted. Additionally, the views measurements work slightly differently inside recyclers and so this is why you see empty spaces. The correct approach would be to remove the items from the data source in the adapter, then refreshing the recycler.

Comment: first solution is simply filter as marcel50506 suggested and second is use getItemType method and return base distance and onCreateViewHolder only create view if it satisfy your base  distance condition otherwise return null.

Comment: Hey Thank you for replying instantly.How can I filter the adapter? @Marcel50506

Comment: Can you explain more the method please.@YasirAli

Comment: I'm not really 'at home' in the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, but it seems that you can pass a query when initializing. From comments in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter github: _The Firebase location to watch for data changes. Can also be a slice of a location, using some combination of <code>limit()</code>, <code>startAt()</code>, and <code>endAt()</code>_ [see here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java)